# document.getElementById('nav').style.width - works then stops

Tags: javascript

I am tryng to do a basic full-screen menu overlay with JavaScript, HTML, CSS.

In my html I have:

`<a href="" class="openBtn" onclick="openNav()">Open</a>`

And in my app.js:

```
$(document).foundation()

// Menu

function  openNav() {
  document.getElementById('nav').style.width = '100%';
}
```

When i click in 'open', the menu shows up and close.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead adding a class

```
function  openNav() {
  document.getElementById('nav').classList.add('show');
}
```

Then add styling for that class in CSS

```
.show{
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: can you set up a demo using jsfiddle.net so I can test?

Comment: I try set up in jsfiddle here:https://jsfiddle.net/maraal/oc5v5Lck.

But when i click to run, the things go bad:

{"error": "Please use POST request"}

Comment: I figured out that was a missing  `#` on the  `<a href="" class="openBtn" onclick="openNav()">Open</a>´. Thank you.

Comment: hmm weird that would cause that error, glad you figured it out